# Art Market data

Tags: data-request, finance

I'm looking for art market related data for research purposes - especially sales in auction houses. I know there are sites like artprice or its free equivalents, but what I'm searching for is something like a structured database, CSV files or linked data ready for further processing, since crawling these sites is forbidden. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try this: http://nycdatascience.com/students-work/webscraping-art-auction-data/

Comment: Anton, that seems worth making a full answer. Of course, if you did, it would be good to make it more than just a link, but it looks reasonably useful.

Comment: @Anton, thanks for your response. However, it is clearly stated on Blouin Art Index that crawling is forbidden: "You may not use any robot, spider, or other automatic or manual device or process to compile or repackage content available via this website in whole or in part."

Comment: mimol, alternatively, you can try extracting from Wikipedia (if it suits) with dbpedia.org or https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-wikipedia

Comment: The first link is broken and it's not clear how can one extract auction results from wikipedia. Are there any auction results in wikipedia at all?

Answer (score 2):

Looking for art market data for a project I found this OKFN (Open Knowledge International) blog post in the field you specify:
[Art Open data](http://blog.okfn.org/2011/02/01/art-open-data/). This leads to a wiki page (not to useful IMHO but it shows you are not alone looking for this kind of data, you can ask in their mailing list also).

I found an "art market for dummies" visualization description on a data-journalism website, but links are broken... Had to go to archive.org to get something useful out of it, this one seem reliable on auctions ad market data:

[MutualArt Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MutualArt.com).

ArtValue has a [http://www.artvalue.com/free-appraisal-art-work.htm](Free art appraisal) page.

The article [Domestic and International Art Market Sales Statistics](http://artbusiness.com/marketdata.html) says "You'll have better luck trying to count the stars in the sky than collecting meaningful art market sales data.", which seems appropriate.

Comment: So far I've found nothing interesting, looks like you have to scrape it on your own (if terms and conditions allows this)...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe start an open database of auction results? It will never be as complete as commercial ones, but I'm sure there are many people who would use it (and  possibly add content).

Comment: not maybe, totally! ;)

Answer (score 1):

buildling off @jilt's answer:
[This PDF has data regarding the art economy](http://imgpublic.artprice.com/pdf/rama2016_en.pdf)
[2014's TEFAF Art Market Report (PDF)](https://www.creatrust.com/medias/fichiers/tefaf_art_market_report_2014.pdf)

Shots in the dark:
[Global Innovation Index 2014](https://www.globalinnovationindex.org/userfiles/file/reportpdf/gii-2014-v5.pdf)
[Google search for "filetype=pdf"+"art"+"economy"](https://www.globalinnovationindex.org/userfiles/file/reportpdf/gii-2014-v5.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I work for Quandl and noticed we have (premium) data on sales for Sotheby's here: https://www.quandl.com/data/ZSS?filterSelection=all&keyword=sotheby%27s

If there are any other publicly traded art companies you wanted to look up, you can try searching for them on Quandl (https://www.quandl.com/) to see if we have data on their sales or revenues.

Comment: The question is more about more about sold lots, not sales/revenues numbers in general - sorry if I haven't made it clear.